# Typo3 - dd_googlesitemap multiple sitemap

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, xml-sitemap

I am using following two extension:

dd_googlesitemap and dd_googlesitemap_dmf

I have two Sitemaps:

Default pages:

```
index.php?Eid=dd_googlesitemap
```

My extension:

```
index.php?Eid=dd_googlesitemap&Sitemap=DMF&selector=myExtSelector
```

**I need only one sitemap.** (for google webmaster tool)

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2006/10/multiple-Sitemaps-in-same-directory.HTML that doesn't work.

Error:

```
XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: nicht wohlgeformt
Adresse: http://www.mydomain.de/sitemap.xml
Zeile Nr. 9, Spalte 55:<loc>http://www.mydomain.de/?eID=dd_googlesitemap&sitemap=dmf&selector=myExtSelector</loc>
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at line 9, character 55 and you'll probably end up near the '&' in the URL. In XML an ampersand is used to start an entity (and a semicolon ends it). In this case the characters following the '&' should be a valid entity name. This is of course not the case here, so you must encode the ampersand.

```
<loc>http://www.mydomain.de/?eID=dd_googlesitemap&amp;sitemap=dmf&amp;selector=myExtSelector</loc>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have known that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use scheduler task. It will create a sitemap index for you from multiple sitemap URLs.

Comment: Hello @dmitry-dulepov, if i try to use the scheduler task "Generate offline sitemap" with this 2 sitemaps [link](https://dgpp.positum.org/index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap) and 
[link](https://dgpp.positum.org/index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap&id=1&sitemap=txnews&singlePid=10&pidList=11&L=0) 
i get the following errors: 
_italic_ Host is missing or does not match any of TYPO3 hosts from the installation.
_italic_ Index file path must be relative to the site's main directory. The referenced directory must exist (the default directory is created when the extension is installed).

Comment: Well, messages are clear. Fix those problems. And don't put a new line after the last sitemap in scheduler config.